# Subclassing UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self) {     
        //My custom code for the view which I will add to the contentView
    }

    return self;
}
```

When I instantiate an object of this class and assign in the datasource - delegate, then it is the same whatever "style" I am using right? (UITableViewCellStyleDefault etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you everything you need add in the contentView and you don't use textLabel, detailTextLabel ect. **Than it is the same, yes**. You could also pass your needed style in

`self = [initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]; // The style is just an example...`

So the given style from outside will be ignored. ;-)